# Make bootstrap navbar fixed after scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my `html` code for the navigation:

```
<div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-sm">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"><i class="fa fa-home fa-lg"></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Services <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)">Rent A Plant</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Why Indoor Plants</a></li>
                                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">F.A.Q's</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Garden Maintenance</a></li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Vertical Gardens</a></li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Artificial Lawns</a></li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Garden Center</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Image Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a href="{{ url('/store') }}" style="background: #916649">E-Store</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Above the navigation I have the logo of `height: 100` and `width: 200`

So, after scrolling down about 130. I want to make the navbar to become fix. So I have used this as my `jQuery`

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
    var navHeight = 130; // custom nav height
    ($(window).scrollTop() > navHeight) ? 
        $('nav').addClass('navbar-fixed-top') :
        $('nav').removeClass('navbar-fixed-top');
});
```

This works completely fine. But the length of the navbar becomes full length which I don't want. I want that it should remain as it is. I mean the fixed length.

How do I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to apply a fixed width to the `nav` element. When you want it centered on the page, also set the left and right margin to `auto`:

```
nav {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    nav { width: 750px; }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    nav { width: 970px; }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    nav { width: 1170px; }
}
```

Comment: This does centers the navbar, but it shrinks the width. I do not want to shrink the width, it has to be the default width of the container.

Comment: Because the `nav` element get a fixed position with the `navbar-fixed-top`,  it's not possible to use the width of it's parent container. You could use css media rules to give it the same width as the container element. I have updated my answer.